# Load hyperlinks with Maatwebsite Laravel-Excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I am importing large xlsx files with Maatwebsite Laravel-Excel into my database. It works just fine, but i can't find a way to import a hyperlink that is linked to some cell in the document. Those links are always processed as simple text without a link that is attached.
Is there a way to receive not only text but also a link or link address?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.

Given:

- `$user['img']` the url of the image
- `$count` your row counter

  $sheet->setCellValue("H{$count}", '=Hyperlink("'.$user['img'].'","View photo")')

Answer (score -1):

`$url = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E26')->getHyperlink()->getUrl();`

First refer to activesheet then the cell from which you want to read the text(as url). For that you need to read using getHyperlink()->getUrl()

Thanks for pointing @bob, New to stackoverflow.

Comment: Keep in mind: A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.